# Get offsetTop when event is fired and don’t refresh it anymore

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I’d like to retrieve the current scroll position when a certain event finishes to append it as a top value for an element.

My problem is that the `offsetTop` value gets updated every time the user scrolls again. How can I save the scroll position at a certain point and store it without being updated?

```
var headerOffsetTop = parseFloat( $( 'header' ).css( 'top' ) );
    headerHeight    = $( 'header' ).height();


if ( headerOffsetTop == -headerHeight ) {

    var offsetTop = $( document ).scrollTop(); // This value should not update anymore on scroll

    $( 'element' ).css( 'top', offsetTop );
    $( 'element' ).removeClass( 'is-fixed' );

} else {

    $( 'element' ).css( 'top', 0 );
    $( 'element' ).addClass( 'is-fixed' );

}
```

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ufa2snr7/2

Comment: I updated my question. With the `if` statement I check if the `header` is out of the viewport.

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand... Is this https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/ufa2snr7/1/ what you want to achieve?

Comment: Not quite. See my fiddle for a better understanding: https://jsfiddle.net/ufa2snr7/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/ufa2snr7/4/ In here it's not updated... If, once again, that is what you wanted to do.
But what did you mean by 'let myDiv be scrollable'? Do you want to hide the header forever once the animation is complete?